# DLLimport in class library unity is not working

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, class-library

I'm trying to call my own dll file into my class library in Unity using this command :

```
[DllImport("files01", EntryPoint = "SaveImg")]
public static extern void SaveImg(byte[] src, int imgWidth, int imgHeight, int filenum);
```

I put my dll inside the 'Assets\Plugins' folder in my Unity project folder. But Unity can't seem to find it. I also try to move my dll into the same folder with my executable Unity file (Assets folder), but Unity still cannot find my dll.

Did I miss something ? Any advice ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're using managed library, you should use [Assembly.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: no. i'm not using managed library.

Comment: Try to use files01.dll

Comment: @GSP not work. Still error "not found"

Comment: Right click on your project >> Add reference >> Browse. Then choose your dll to add into project

Comment: @GSP I'm in Unity. I don't think there's a way to Add Reference like that.

Comment: Don't add a reference. It's not managed.

Comment: Is it your dll that can't be found, or its dependencies?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's my dll files that can't be found

Comment: Where is the system looking? In the executable folder. I don't know Unity but I guess that's somewhere completely apart from your project files. In which case I suggest that you p/invoke `LoadLibrary` and call it passing the full path to your DLL. Then subsequent p/invoke calls will use that module because it is already loaded.

Comment: Well, in Unity we're 'suggested' to put our dll files into folder Assets/Plugins, where the executable folder is the Assets itself. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) . I'm not that familiar with P/invoke, I'll try to get some information about it and update my progress.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898629/unable-to-find-type-or-namespace-of-imported-dll